# Where would you ask a subjective QA question

Tags: discussion

I want to ask a question about people's experience of using specific testing technique. Since opinions are not very welcomed at StackExchange, I wonder where one would ask a subjective question on QA.

Comment: Softwaretestingclub.com ? :)

Comment: @PhilKirkham Softwaretestingclub.com is not working!

Comment: http://www.softwaretestingclub.com

Comment: What do you mean opinions are not welcomed here?

Comment: @user246 I would actually say that this question belongs here if anywhere, but I'm not sure if it is actually a good question for the site. I do think your suggestion of going to meta and asking "Is XYZ allowed here?" is a good one, as is just asking the 'subjective' question and seeing what feedback it gets.

Comment: @SayusiAndo Primarily opinion based questions are discouraged. They should be based in fact, logic and experience where possible. Check out this blog post: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Answer (score 3):

As there has been a couple of good suggestions in the comment section, please close this question.

From the comment section:

```
flag
```

Softwaretestingclub.com ? :) –  Phil Kirkham Feb 11 '14 at 23:23

@PhilKirkham Softwaretestingclub.com is not working! –  Emmanuel Angelo.R Feb 12 '14 at 5:36

softwaretestingclub.com –  Phil Kirkham Feb 12 '14 at 12:59

What do you mean opinions are not welcomed here? –  SayusiAndo Feb 12 '14 at 16:03

> **@user246**: I would actually say that this question belongs here if anywhere, but I'm not sure if it is actually a good question for the site. I do think your suggestion of going to meta and asking "Is XYZ allowed here?" is a good one, as is just asking the 'subjective' question and seeing what feedback it gets. –  corsiKa♦ Feb 14 '14 at 18:32

---

> **@SayusiAndo:** Primarily opinion based questions are discouraged. They should be based in fact, logic and experience where possible. Check out this blog post: blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective –  corsiKa♦ Feb 14 '14 at 18:32